# Is it possible to use Flex UI components with Starling?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, starling-framework

I am using Flex to build a web based viewer, although I can build it in a pure actionscript 3.0 project, but I thought using Flex will save us time building complex UI components ..

So, as the question implies, can we use those Flex UI components with starling? 
Is it as easy as adding the UI component to the Starling  ex .. starling.display.Sprite rather than to the conventional display list? is that all?

I hope I can find a clear answer here, otherwise Flex as an option will be questionable or canceled ..

Well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex components inherit Flash sprites which are not the same as Starling's sprites. So the answer is no, Starling won't let you add a Flex component.
Flex component are coded using the native Flash display list, you would have to recode them entirely using Starling.

Comment: Oh, that's the truth that I was trying not to see, do you know if there is a set of rich UIs components using Starling?